# Unable to open bash profile on OSX

Tags: macos

I am unable to open bash profile. I had set the Java and Android path but suddenly it is opening. But when I run echo $PATH it is displaying the paths correctly. Now I need to add path to bash profile.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: `bash profile` => How do you try it ?

Comment: I tried with open -e .bash_profile and vim ~/.bash_profile

Comment: What's the output of `cd && ls -al .*` ?

Comment: for cd it is not showing anything and for ls -al .* it displays "ls command not found".

Comment: And if you type `/bin/ls -al ~/.*` ? By the way, what's the content of your $PATH ?

Comment: It is displying list of files with thier access levels, for bash profile it is "-rw-r--r--@  1 user    184 May 28 09:54 .bash_profile".

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$PATH` is wrong :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/qsgte‌​chnologies/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/qsgtechnologies/Library/Andr‌​oid/sdk/tools
```

This doesn't use standard default path, and, unless this is totally intentional, I recommend you not to do this.

You've got to fix it running this (note `/bin:/usr/bin:`):

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/qsgte‌​chnologies/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/qsgtechnologies/Library/Andr‌​oid/sdk/tools:
```

The next time, be sure to use this syntax:

```
export PATH=$PATH/YourNewPath:
```

---

Since you removed `/bin:/usr/bin:` you where unable to change your bash profile because bash wasn't able to locate your executables.

---

Fitting your needs, here's your current `bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) 
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/qsgtechnologies/Library/Android/sdk 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Change it to (note that `YourNewEntry` is a placeholder for the value you need)

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) 
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/qsgtechnologies/Library/Android/sdk 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/YourNewEntry
```

Then apply your changes:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, again I am facing the same issue. Could you please help me to sort out. some of the comments have been removed here..

Comment: What's your state now ? @DeepaS

Comment: It shows -bash: open: command not found when i try open bash profile

Comment: For all commands im getting command not found only please help me to sort out it.

Comment: We need to fix the root and not the consequences @DeepaS. What did you do between the time it worked to now ?

Comment: I tried to enable the root access with dsenableroot and tried to open bash profile but still it shows command not found

Comment: last week also I had the same issue but solved it by following the steps you had given..

Comment: @DeepaS run this `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/qsgte‌​chnologies/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/qsgtechnologies/Library/Andr‌​oid/sdk/tools:`

Comment: Yes, now I am able to open.. Thank you so much.. y it happens like this?

Comment: @DeepaS because, *somewhere/somehow*, your `$PATH` changes and as long as you don't fix this, you'll get in trouble again.